# BackboneJS Youtube player only renders once

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, youtube

I have a BackboneJS App where I display Youtube Videos on my View. So when user clicks on a thumbnail the Youtube-iframe opens and plays the video. When user closes it and wants to play it again, nothing happens. To show it again, the user has to refresh the page which is not good.

My View looks like this:

```
function (App, Backbone, ArtistVideos, Artistimg, Artistname) {

    var ArtistVideoPopup = App.module();

    ArtistVideoPopup.View = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: 'artistYoutubeVideo',
        initialize: function () {

        },      
        beforeRender: function() {
            $("#vid").before("<div id='vidoverlay'></div>");
            $("#vid").after("<div id='closeDiv'><button title='Luk (Esc)' type='button' class='mdk-close'>×</button></div>")

            var artistimgCollection = new Artistimg.ArtistimgCollection();
            artistimgCollection.artist_id = this.artist_id;
            this.insertView('.artistImage', new Artistimg.View({collection: artistimgCollection}));
            artistimgCollection.fetch();

            var artistnameCollection = new Artistname.ArtistnameCollection();
            artistnameCollection.artist_id = this.artist_id;
            this.insertView('.artistName', new Artistname.View({collection: artistnameCollection}));
            artistnameCollection.fetch();

            var artistvideosModel = new ArtistVideos.ArtistVideosModel();
            artistvideosModel.artist_id = this.artist_id;
            artistvideosModel.video_youtube_id = this.video_youtube_id;
            artistvideosModel.fetch();
        },  

        afterRender: function() {

            $('ul.acmenu li a.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $('ul.acmenu li a.artistVideos').addClass('selected');          

            var tag = document.createElement('script');

            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            var player;
            window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = _.bind(function() {
              player = new YT.Player('vid', {
                height: '480',
                width: '853',
                videoId: this.video_youtube_id,
                events: {
                  onReady: onPlayerReady,
                  onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
                }
             })
            }, this);

            function onPlayerReady(event) {
                event.target.playVideo();
            }

            var done = false;
            function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                    //setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
                    done = true;
                }
            }
            function stopVideo() {
                player.stopVideo();
            }

            $(".mdk-close").click(function(){
                $(this).hide();
                $("#vidoverlay").fadeOut(500);
                $("#vid").fadeOut(500);
                var video = $("#vid").attr("src");
                $("#vid").attr("src","");
                $("#vid").attr("src",video);

            });             

        }

    });

    return ArtistVideoPopup;
}
```

Like mentioned before, it only renders once! As soon I close it, the video-iframe does not appear before i reload the whole page again.

So does anyone know what might be the issue here? Please help...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really tested yet, but give this a shot:

```
function (App, Backbone, ArtistVideos, Artistimg, Artistname) {

    var ArtistVideoPopup = App.module();

    // Create a new Deferred for the YouTube IFrame API
    var loadYouTubeAPI = $.Deferred();

    // When the API is ready then resolve the Deferred's promise()
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = loadYouTubeAPI.resolve;

    // Convert the Deferred into its own promise() so nothing else can
    // resolve or reject it before onYouTubeIframeAPIReady is called
    loadYouTubeAPI = loadYouTubeAPI.promise();

    // Begin download of YouTube IFrame API
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // Helpful function to get the player state as a string from an int
    var playerState = function(data){
        switch (data) {
            case -1: return 'unstarted';
            case  0: return 'ended';
            case  1: return 'playing';
            case  2: return 'paused';
            case  3: return 'buffering';
            case  5: return 'cued';
            default: return 'quantum';
        }
    }

    ArtistVideoPopup.View = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: 'artistYoutubeVideo',
        initialize: function(){
            _.bindAll(this, 'onAPIReady', 'closePlayer');
            this.$iframe = $('#vid');
            this.iframe  = this.$iframe.get(0);
            loadYouTubeAPI.then(this.onAPIReady);
        },
        onAPIReady: function(){
            this.player = new YT.Player(this.iframe, {
                height: '480',
                width:  '853',
                videoId: this.video_youtube_id,
                events: {
                    onReady: this.onPlayerReady,
                    onStateChange: this.onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        },
        onPlayerReady: function(e){
            e.target.playVideo();
        },
        onPlayerStateChange: function(e){
            console.log(playerState(e.data));
        },
        closePlayer: function(e){
            $(e.currentTarget).hide();
            $("#vidoverlay").fadeOut(500);
            this.$iframe.fadeOut(500).done(this.onPlayerClose);
        },
        onPlayerClose: function(){
            if (this.player) {
                this.player.stopVideo();
            }
        },
        beforeRender: function() {
            this.$iframe
                .before("<div id='vidoverlay'></div>")
                .after("<div id='closeDiv'><button title='Luk (Esc)' type='button' class='mdk-close'>×</button></div>")

            var artistimgCollection = new Artistimg.ArtistimgCollection();
            artistimgCollection.artist_id = this.artist_id;
            this.insertView('.artistImage', new Artistimg.View({collection: artistimgCollection}));
            artistimgCollection.fetch();

            var artistnameCollection = new Artistname.ArtistnameCollection();
            artistnameCollection.artist_id = this.artist_id;
            this.insertView('.artistName', new Artistname.View({collection: artistnameCollection}));
            artistnameCollection.fetch();

            var artistvideosModel = new ArtistVideos.ArtistVideosModel();
            artistvideosModel.artist_id = this.artist_id;
            artistvideosModel.video_youtube_id = this.video_youtube_id;
            artistvideosModel.fetch();
        },
        afterRender: function() {
            this.$iframe.show();
            $('ul.acmenu li a.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $('ul.acmenu li a.artistVideos').addClass('selected');
            $("#closeDiv").on('click', '.mdk-close', this.onPlayerClose);
        }
    });
    return ArtistVideoPopup;
}
```

Comment: @SHT does the `#vid` iframe exist on the page before this view gets initialized?